# What duplicates can I delete from Pierre Boulez's Complete Works (by DG), vs. his Complete Columbia Album Collection?

Tags: modernism

By "duplicate", I mean the selfsame piece, performers, and performance.
Disregard the same piece ***PERFORMED DIFFERENTLY, e.g. different performers or time.***

What's duplicated between Pierre Boulez's

- [The Complete Columbia Album Collection](https://www.discogs.com/release/10002496-Pierre-Boulez-The-Complete-Columbia-Album-Collection) released by Sony Classical
- vs. [Œuvres Complètes = Complete Works](https://www.discogs.com/release/5290283-Pierre-Boulez-%C5%92uvres-Compl%C3%A8tes-Complete-Works) released by Deutsche Grammophon?

What duplicates can I delete, if any? I need to free hard drive space.